# Series of sine functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please is it correct to argue the following?

Let us define the equations:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n))=0,\\  
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n)+\varphi)=0,\\  
$$
$$
x\in (0,1), y\in \mathbb{R}, \varphi\neq k\pi, k\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
Then their solutions $(x,y)$ are $(Re(\varrho_{k}),Im(\varrho_{k})), k\in\mathbb{N}$ where
$\varrho_{k}$ are non trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

The imaginary part of the exponent of the Dirichlet eta function can be expressed in a goniometric form:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}n^{-x-iy} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}n^{-x}\cos(y\ln(n)) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x}i\sin(y\ln(n)).\\  
$$
The Dirichlet eta function is equal to zero when the real part and the imaginary part of the goniometric form are both equal to zero.

Then the real part and the imaginary part of the goniometric form was separated, set equal to zero and the imaginary unit was removed:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n))=0,\\  
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x}\cos(y\ln(n))=0.\\  
$$
These equations have the same solutions with the term $(-1)^{n}$ as with the term $(-1)^{n+1}$.

Subsequently, the cosine function was expressed by using the sine function:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n))=0,\\  
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n)+\frac{\pi}{2})=0.\\  
$$
Their solutions $(x,y)$ are $(Re(\varrho_{k}),Im(\varrho_{k})), k\in\mathbb{N}$ where $\varrho_{k}$ are non trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

Finally, the term $\frac{\pi}{2}$ was replaced by a general angle $\varphi$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n))=0,\\  
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n)+\varphi)=0,\\  
$$
which is the set of equations defined above. A similar set of equations can be defined with the cosine function.

Their solutions $(x,y)$ are also $(Re(\varrho_{k}),Im(\varrho_{k})), k\in\mathbb{N}$ where $\varrho_{k}$ are non trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

If the both sine functions are phase shifted by an integer multiple of $\pi$, solutions of the both sine series coincide. If the both sine functions are phase shifted differently from by an integer multiple of $\pi$, solutions of the both sine series intersect each other in $(x,y)$ corresponding to the real part and the imaginary part of non trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

Hence, the term $n^{-x}$ works as a weight function of the sine function and the cosine function. It seems that the value $x=\frac{1}{2}$ guarantees that any phase shift is eliminated and the both series are zeroed at the same $(x,y)$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148205/discussion-on-question-by-martin-pribyl-series-of-sine-functions); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Figure (1) below illustrates $\left|f_\varphi\left(\rho_3\right)\right|$ as a function of $\varphi$ over the range $0<\varphi<2\, \pi$ where $\rho_3$ is the third non-trivial zeta-zero in the upper half-plane using formula (1) below evaluated at $N=1000$. Note $\left|f_\varphi\left(\rho_3\right)\right|$ only seems to evaluate to $0$ at $\varphi=\frac{\pi}{2}$ in which case $f_\varphi(s)$ evaluates to the Dirichlet eta function $\eta(s)$.

$$f_\varphi(s)=1-\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum_{n=2}^N (-1)^n\, n^{-\Re(s)}\, (\sin(\varphi-\Im(s)\, \log(n))+i\, \sin(-\Im(s)\, \log(n)))\right)\tag{1}$$

[image]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $\left|f_\varphi\left(\rho_3\right)\right|$ over the range $0<\varphi<2\, \pi$